# If x2 & x3 affect x1, & x1 affects y, should x2 & x3 be included in a regression model?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, multicollinearity, mediation

Let's consider the regression $y=x_1+x_2+x_3+\varepsilon$

It is known that $x_2$ and $x_3$ affect $x_1$, but $x_2$ and $x_3$ do not affect $y$. $x_1$ can affect $y$, but only to a small extent. The RMSE is slightly lower if we add $x_2$ and $x_3$ compared to when regressing $y=x_1+\varepsilon$.

There is no multicollinearity. Given the goal that we want to estimate the effects of $x_1$ on $y$, what are the arguments for including or excluding $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the regressions? An argument in favor of adding $x_2$ and $x_3$: Is it that we can estimate the pure effects of $x_1$ on $y$?

Comment: If $x_2$ and $x_3$ affect $x_1$ how can there be no multicollinearity?

Comment: There is a correlation of $x_1$ with $x_2$ and $x_3$, but not high. Thus, there is no multicollinearity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation you are referring to is called [mediation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_%28statistics%29).

Whether you should include $x_2$ and $x_3$ depends on what you want from your model.  If you want to test models of complex relationships (e.g., comparing partial mediation to complete mediation), you may want to use [structural equations modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling) (SEM).  If you simply want to predict $y$ as best as possible, $x_2$ and $x_3$ may or may not help.  (Note that adding them has to reduce the RMSE, whether the variables are appropriate or not.)

Whether or not adding $x_2$ and $x_3$ helps you estimate the "pure" effect of $x_1$ depends on the nature of the data generating process.  For example, they would 'purify' the relationship if they act as a suppressor.  Suppression is a difficult and counter-intuitive topic, to start learning about it, you could try reading this excellent CV thread:  [Suppression effect in regression: definition and visual explanation/depiction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/73869/7290) ([this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34016/7290) or [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/143368/7290) may help as well).

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a very quick reply and a detailed answer. I was unfamiliar with the term mediation. Also, I am going to read through that link.